# How to reload admin grid table with js?

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax, uicomponent, knockoutjs

Is there any way to reload custom admin ui grid with ajax? Just like it reloads when you for example sorting by clicking a column name. I just need this grid table to be updated with new data. Is there any js function for that in magento 2 ?

Comment: I think we should have a button to trigger the ajax, when click this button, the ajax will be call and the grid will be updated?

Comment: What I tiring to ask - is there any js api function for that?

Comment: See: [How to Reload Ui Component Grid Table with Js In Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153949/how-to-reload-ui-component-grid-table-with-js-in-magento-2/192146#192146)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself. The answer is simple: `transactionGridJsObject.resetFilter()`

Comment: Could you please give more details? where do you put this code? how you execute it?