# Magento2 Admin UI Component: On fileUploader ajax completion in ui component, how can I reload the page it is on?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, magento2.3.0, file-upload, admin-controller

I have a grid that just shows a collection of a specific table.

below is a file upload component that I want to use for CSV upload, that will replace all old collection. Image reference is below:

[image]

When the file is uploaded, ajax completes, I need to reload the grid page so that new data is loaded and

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Batch upload Success');
```

is displayed.

Please tell how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below way.

Add below code in your ajax success function.

```
success: function (data) {
         transactionGridJsObject.resetFilter() 
}
```

If you still not getting the solution then try with below way.

- [How to load Ui component grid table](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153949/how-to-reload-ui-component-grid-table-with-js-in-magento-2/192146#192146)
- [Reload page if ajax is success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654298/jquery-refresh-reload-page-if-ajax-success-after-time)
- [Successs message after ajax response](http://www.degtil.com/2017/12/22/magento-2-display-error-messages-ajax-request-custom-page/)

I hope it helps!